# fhem interface not started

Tags: linux, perl, raspberry-pi, port

I followed [this](https://www.enocean.com/fileadmin/redaktion/pdf/white_paper/wp_Raspberry_talks_EnOcean.pdf) tutorial to install fhem on my **Raspberry Pi**:

But the fhem interface is not started in my web navigator when I put:

```
http://192.168.1.5:8083/fhem
```

"192.168.1.5" is my raspberry pi address

I checked processes in Linux, perl is listening on the port 8083:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2207/perl
```

PS: KURA eclipse project is installed on my **Raspberry Pi**.

What is wrong? what I have missed?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed Kura, it is acting as a firewall so you need to use the Kura Web UI to open tcp port 8083, which is filtered by default.

[image: Kura Firewall]